# How to use Rules to send an email to an email id based on a selected in a registration form?

Tags: users, emails

I have created a rule for sending an email after a new user registered. I would like to add a Rules Condition to send the email to the target based on the selection in the registration form.

For example: if I select the country as india I need to send to india@gmail.com and for other others@gmail.com.

I have tried adding a condition in To mail receipt address:

```
$email = ($account->country == 'india'? india@gmail.com : 'other@gmail.com')
echo $email;
```

Can you suggest how to handle the scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get this to work by creating a single rule using the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module (and [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) of course). The rule should be trigger by Rules Event "*after saving a new user account*".

For some samples to put together such rule (in Rules export format), refer to my answer to either of these questions:

- [How to set the values of some fields depending on the value of a list box?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/159293/how-to-set-the-values-of-some-fields-depending-on-the-value-of-a-list-box/192904#192904)
- [How to specify a Rules condition related to select list values?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/175988/how-to-specify-a-rules-condition-related-to-select-list-values/176180#176180)

The actual Rules Action you want to use, should be pretty similar to the Rules Action included in my answer to "[How to send an email via a Rules action using a field key?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/176913/how-to-send-an-email-via-a-rules-action-using-a-field-key/177035#177035)".